# Extract some pages in Acrobat DC and save that file

Tags: javascript, pdf, acrobat

I am writing a function that extracts some pages from a document so it can be used as proof. I have used a switch case that if it is true will output some pages. In the third case I want to extract the first two pages of the document, the 23rd and 24th and the two last pages. This is what I cant solve. Can I just use the this.extractPages method or do I have to use the insertPages method also. If I need the insertPages method how do I use it. The code is inside a trusted function.

```
switch (true){
case this.numPages == 1:
this.extractPages(0,0, newPath);
app.alert("A one paged proof has been created",3)
break;

case ( (this.numPages > 1) && (this.numPages < 9) ):
this.extractPages(0,1, newPath);
app.alert("A two paged proof has been created",3)
break;

(PROBLEM IS HERE)
case ( (this.numPages > 9) && (this.numPages < 49) ):
this.extractPages(0,1, newPath);
app.alert("A proof has been created",3)
break;

default:
app.alert("No proof has been created",3)
break;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the third case, you'd need to extract the three parts separately, save to disk separately, then and stitch them back together leaving a bunch of smaller files that Acrobat can't delete. You're better off just deleting the pages you don't need from the source and then saving to a new file.

Comment: Thank you very much for your information. You are right, I will try to just delete the pages I dont need and then save. I will try to figure out which methods to use. Thank you!

Comment: Use this.deletePages(nStart, nEnd) but start from the back, that way you won't need to recalculate the page numbers as you delete the ones you don't want. Remember page numbers are zero based. Then this.saveAs() with the path to the new file.

Comment: this.deletePages(this.numPages-2,this.numPages/2); its not working for some reasons im trying to work from the back

Comment: Even though you're working from the back, the first number still has to be lower than the second number. I was just saying work from the back in groups, not reversing the page numbers.